# ggplot2, uso de paste en geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-dplyr

Hola estoy intentando colocar el valor de las barras de mi gráfica, pero no consigo hacer lo que realmente estoy buscando.

Tengo el siguiente dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  'proposito'= c('coche','coche','casa','casa','moto','moto'),
  'pagado' = c('si','no','si','no','si','no'),
  'total' = c(50,13,75,19,32,25))
```

Cuando hago la gráfica obtengo lo siguiente

```
df %>% ggplot()+
  aes(proposito, total, fill=pagado)+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("olivedrab3","slategray3"))+
  theme_minimal()+
  coord_flip()+
  geom_text(aes(label=paste(total,'/',total)))+
  labs(title='Propósito de los créditos',
       subtitle='Cumplen o no las condiciones',
       y='Propósito',
       x='Totales')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría tener el geom_text al final de cada barra (después de la zona verde) y de la forma total1/total2, por ejemplo para la barra apilada coche 13/50 la de casa 19/75.

He probado varias opciones pero no lo logro. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: creo que con hjust lo resuelves: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26684121/4717133

Comment: Hola Francisco, es justo lo que ha hecho Patricio debajo. Pero gracias por tu aportación.

Answer (score 1):

Conviene "preparar" los datos para la gráfica, necesitas: 1) Un total por cada grupo (`proposito`) para poder ubicar las etiquetas 2) El `label` que se construye con los valores de "si" y "no" por cada grupo:

```
df %>% 
  left_join(df %>% 
              pivot_wider(names_from=pagado, values_from=total) %>% 
              mutate(label=paste(si, "/", no)) %>% 
              select(proposito, label),
            by = "proposito"
  ) %>% 
  group_by(proposito) %>% 
  mutate(total_proposito = sum(total)) %>% 
  ungroup() -> plot_data

plot_data

# A tibble: 6 x 5
  proposito pagado total label   total_proposito
  <chr>     <chr>  <dbl> <chr>             <dbl>
1 coche     si        50 50 / 13              63
2 coche     no        13 50 / 13              63
3 casa      si        75 75 / 19              94
4 casa      no        19 75 / 19              94
5 moto      si        32 32 / 25              57
6 moto      no        25 32 / 25              57
```

---

Con `pivot_wider` transformamos los valores "si" y "no" en columnas, para poder construir `label`, con un `left_join` lo unimos a los datos y calculamos el total por grupo. Ahora simplemente modificamos la estética del `geom_text()`:

```
plot_data %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(proposito, total, fill=pagado) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("olivedrab3","slategray3")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(aes(label=label,
                y = total_proposito + 7 )) +
  labs(title='Propósito de los créditos',
       subtitle='Cumplen o no las condiciones',
       y='Propósito',
       x='Totales')
```

---

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Patricio. Casi das en el clavo, me explico.  En el caso de la moto el texto que quiero que aparezca es únicamente 32/25, para coche 50/13 y para casa 75/19. Es decir, los valores de cada barra apilada pero sin el total de las 2 juntas.

Comment: @DavidMolina Revisa mi última edición. Saludos.

Comment: Ahora es perfecto. Buscando, había encontrado la función pivot_wider pero no era capaz de sacarlo tampoco. Muchas gracias Patricio, un placer.